# What is wrong here in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, style, reduced-relative-clauses

Would someone help me figure out why this sentence sounds off, and help me rewrite it?

> We're talking about a group of people so deeply-rooted in and so appreciative of
>   their ancient past, yet advancing rapidly into the future.

In the first half of the sentence

> We're talking about a group of people so deeply-rooted in and so appreciative of
>   their ancient past

I try to use the style of omitting 'the relative pronoun + the verb *be*' construct (who are).

Yet a challenge arises in the second half of the sentence.

> . . . , yet advancing rapidly into the future.

I am trying to create a parallelism effect, but when I omit "who are" in the second half of the sentence, it sounds off for a reason I can't put my fingers on. And if I write "yet who are advancing . . . ", it still sounds very awkward because the first half of the sentence omits "who are."

Answer (score 1):

I think the "so" is off in your example. "So" is usually followed by "that":

> - I was **so** tired from running constantly **that** I had to stop to catch a breath.
> - The alien technology is **so** advanced **that** we can't even begin to understand it.

Your sentence looks better with the "so" removed:

> We're talking about a group of people deeply-rooted in and appreciative of their ancient past, yet advancing rapidly into the future.

Or with something added in:

> We're talking about a group of people so deeply-rooted in and so appreciative of their ancient past *that it's hard to imagine them letting it go*, yet *we're seeing them* advancing rapidly into the future.